# "privacy" is not accepted, when posting to a Page's wall with a Pagetoken

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geotargetting

**Goal:**

I want to specify privacy for posts, that are done through my application, when I post to a Page's wall, using Pagetoken.

**Problem:**

Using page token, I do post to URL "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"
with the following body —

> {
>
> ```
>    "message": "from app with security after requesting a username",
>    "privacy": {
>        "description": "Amsterdam, Netherlands, Netherlands",
>        "value": "CUSTOM"
>    }
> ```
>
> }

An receive such a terrible answer —

> {
>
> ```
>    "error": {
>    "message": "(#100) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include privacy.",
>    "type": "OAuthException"
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Even through it is said in documentation, here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts,
that Pages#post.privacy is supported.

And explicitly:

> "The description field may contain a comma-separated lists of valid country, city and language if a Page's post targeting by location/language is specified."

Please help me out, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I posted the bug in Facebook Developers Bug reporter tool
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238365492903384

Subscribe/Comment to push this for a reply

Comment: got a response from FB: Posts made by a page do not have privacy settings, they're always visible to everyone unless targetted using the appropriate options.
Also, posts made via the API do not have a 'share' link in the same way that manually created posts do - this is intentional

Comment: Thanks alot. Thou I'm not concerned about "share" link that much, but to be able geo-target my posts with "privacy" option.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a documentation bug.  I have attached a screenshot of the old version of the docs.  Try using "targeting" with the same location format as:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/adsapi/targeting_specs/

[image]

I've also requested a fix for the docs.